# Django modelform NOT required field

Tags: django, django-forms, option-type, django-models

I have a form like this:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')
```

How can I set the address field as optional?

Comment: What does the model look like?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Guess your model is like this:

```
class My_Class(models.Model):

    address = models.CharField()
```

Your form for Django version < 1.8:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):

    address = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')
```

Your form for Django version > 1.8:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):

    address = forms.CharField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')
```

Shameless plug: Check your Python knowledge at http://python.softwarequizzes.com

Comment: What about foreign key field?

Comment: Use ModelChoiceField. So, if field definitions is `abc=models.ForeignKey(Abc)`, you can write `abc = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Abc.objects.all(), required=False)`

Comment: Make sure that forms is imported if you weren't using it before: `from django import forms`

Comment: Are you sure Django > 1.8 is supposed to accept `blank=True`? The docs say otherwise and my code doesn't like it, they say I should use `required=False`. Did you get your signs inverted?

Answer (score 147):

```
class My_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(My_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['address'].required = False
```

Comment: Altough the answer of akshar looks better, this method prevents you have to do stuff to set stuff like help_text and label.

Comment: This method is especially helpful in dealing with fields which are defined as FKs at model level. By akshar's method, one would have to set the `queryset` attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't you put `self.fields['address'].required = False` before `super(My_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`!?

Comment: @chakmeshma you won't override anything in that case =)

Answer (score 30):

```
field = models.CharField(max_length=9, default='', blank=True)
```

Just add `blank=True` in your model field and it won't be required when you're using `modelforms`.

"If the model field has `blank=True`, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, `required=True`."

source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types

[Edit]: Change Django doc link from 4.1 to 5.0

Comment: Should be noted that if you are submitting forms manually as in `MyForm(form_data).is_valid()`, then the field must not be referenced in `form_data`. If it is included, but sent to a blank or None value, it seems it can still trigger the validation error.

Comment: @AdamStarrh I can confirm that exception

Comment: The op is using a modelform, the resulting form mirrors the fields in the model, if you need any extra fields (manually inserted) in the form that are mandatory, this data must come from another source to be complemented.

Answer (score 9):

You would have to add:

```
address = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Comment: The blank and null attributes are not used for ModelForms

Comment: this should be in the _model_ field, not the form field. `null=True, blank=True` will cause the ModelForm field to be `required=False`

Answer (score 6):

Solution: use both `blank=True`, `null=True`.

```
my_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Explanation:

If you use `null=True`

```
my_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

then `my_field` is required, with `*` next to it in the form and you can't submit the empty value.

If you use `blank=True`

```
my_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
```

then `my_field` is not required, there won't be a `*` next to it in the form and you can't submit the value. But it will get null field not allowed.

Note: marking as not required and allowing null fields are two different things.

Pro Tip: Read the error more carefully than documentation.

Comment: This answer works for fields that are not CharField or TextField. For these you do not want both null and blank because then there are multiple representations of empty.

Answer (score 5):

[@Anentropic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205908/django-modelform-not-required-field#comment73058095_25187863) from the comment on [@Atma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187863/4345461) worked for me. And I think it's the best one too.

His comment:

> `null=True, blank=True` will cause the `ModelForm` field to be `required=False`

I just set it on my ManyToMany field in my `UserProfile` class and it worked flawlessly.

My `UserProfile` class now looks like this (notice the `friends` field):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

I also think that this is the most beautiful solution since you do the same thing, put `null` and `blank` to `True`, weather you have a simple `char` field or, like I have, `ManyToMany` field.

Comment: for `ManyToManyField`, `blank=True` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct; nevertheless due note that setting `null=True` on a ManyToManyField has no effect at the database level and will raise the following warning when migrating:

`(fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.`

A good answer to this is explained in this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243039/migrating-manytomanyfield-to-null-true-blank-true-isnt-recognized/18244527).